# Нужны ли в этих фразах кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Молчалина можно отнести к "фамусовскому" обществу.

Молчалина можно отнести к "фамусовскому" поколению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не ставил. Это не вновь вводимый термин, значение не переносное.
Вообще очень много в таких случаях зависит от стиля текста. Но, судя по упоминанию Молчалина, тут именно о фамусовском поколении и фамусовском обществе идёт речь.